# Joining up data in several rows into one row in Google Sheets

Tags: join, google-sheets

I have a table in Google Sheets where the columns look something like this:

**Name; ID; Address; Phone no.; Date;**

I have duplicates in the name and ID columns and then **some** data in the following cells, but I have the rest of the data in a separate row, such as:

1. James; 01; a; NULL; NULL;
2. James; 01; NULL; +36907851236; 09.12.2019.;
3. Mark; 02; b; NULL; NULL;
4. Mark; 02; NULL; +36402584796;04.03.2019.;

Basically what I'm trying to demonstrate is that I have several rows of the same person, with some data in one row and some data in another. What I'm trying to do is to merge/join up these rows without

- losing any data
- having to do it manually as there are several hundred rows

What I want, based on the "table" above:

1. James; 01; a; +36907851236; 09.12.2019.;
2. Mark; 02; b; +36402584796;04.03.2019.;

I know basically nothing about the script editor, so if it's possible to do this without that, it would be best. If not, please keep it as simple as possible.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I rearranged the ID and Name columns as this makes more sense. Now we have columns:

```
ID  Name    Address Phone   Date
```

You can use formulas for each column:

- ID,Name: `=UNIQUE(A2:B)`
- Name:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(
    ""&TRANSPOSE(
        SPLIT(
            REGEXREPLACE(
                TEXTJOIN(
                    ",",
                    ,
                    UNIQUE(
                        TRANSPOSE(
                            IF(
                                TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A2:$A,LEN($A2:$A)))=FILTER($A2:$A,LEN($A2:$A)),
                                FILTER(C2:C,LEN(C2:C)),
                                ";"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                ",(;,)+",
                ";"
            ),
            ";"
        )
    ),
    ",?NULL,?",
))
```

The `UNIQUE` + `TRANSPOSE` bit does a sort of group join/concatenate when used in an `ArrayFormula`.

- Phone: drag the name formula over
- Date: I'm not sure if this is a locale setting. (My locale uses slashes to delimit dates.) If it's the same for you and you plan use strings, then you can just drag the formula over again. Otherwise, you'll have the extra step of adding `TEXT(FILTER(E2:E,LEN(E2:E)),"MM.DD.YYYY")` to your date to convert it to a string after you drag it over.